# Ошибка приложения в Android Studio

Tags: java, android

Это уже третий вопрос по этой теме, перепробовал все что только смог придумать. Instant Run отключен, минимальная API 19  (у телефона тоже 19) код на ошибки проверил, что делать дальше не знаю. Когда нажимаю на кнопку в приложении оно вылетает. Вот код из java файла :

```
package com.example.user.myapplication;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    Button button;
    TextView text;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
        text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text);

        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                text.setText("Нажата кнопка");
            }
        });

    }
}
```

Код из xml файла:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.user.myapplication.MainActivity">

    <Button
        android:text="@string/button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:id="@+id/button" />

    <TextView
        android:text="@string/text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/button"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="78dp"
        android:id="@+id/textView" /> 
</RelativeLayout>
```

Логи:

```
07-24 16:21:30.131 16973-16995/? E/JavaBinder: !!! FAILED BINDER TRANSACTION !!!
07-24 16:21:30.131 16973-16995/? W/dalvikvm: threadid=11: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4156fbc0)
07-24 16:21:30.131 16973-16995/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: TaskWorker
               Process: com.htc.launcher, PID: 16973
               java.lang.RuntimeException: Package manager has died
                   at android.app.ApplicationPackageManager.getPackageInfo(ApplicationPackageManager.java:81)
                   at com.htc.launcher.ExternalAppStateList.isExternal(ExternalAppStateList.java:249)
                   at com.htc.launcher.ExternalAppStateList.onExternalAppStateChange(ExternalAppStateList.java:120)
                   at com.htc.launcher.ExternalAppStateList.onReceiveBroadcast(ExternalAppStateList.java:71)
                   at com.htc.launcher.ExternalAppStateList$ExternalChangedTask.run(ExternalAppStateList.java:418)
                   at com.htc.launcher.task.TaskWorker$TagRunnable.run(TaskWorker.java:156)
                   at com.htc.launcher.task.TaskWorker$DeferredHandler$Impl.handleMessage(TaskWorker.java:230)
                   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
                   at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:61)
                Caused by: android.os.TransactionTooLargeException
                   at android.os.BinderProxy.transact(Native Method)
                   at android.content.pm.IPackageManager$Stub$Proxy.getPackageInfo(IPackageManager.java:1639)
                   at android.app.ApplicationPackageManager.getPackageInfo(ApplicationPackageManager.java:76)
                   at com.htc.launcher.ExternalAppStateList.isExternal(ExternalAppStateList.java:249) 
                   at com.htc.launcher.ExternalAppStateList.onExternalAppStateChange(ExternalAppStateList.java:120) 
                   at com.htc.launcher.ExternalAppStateList.onReceiveBroadcast(ExternalAppStateList.java:71) 
                   at com.htc.launcher.ExternalAppStateList$ExternalChangedTask.run(ExternalAppStateList.java:418) 
                   at com.htc.launcher.task.TaskWorker$TagRunnable.run(TaskWorker.java:156) 
                   at com.htc.launcher.task.TaskWorker$DeferredHandler$Impl.handleMessage(TaskWorker.java:230) 
                   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136) 
                   at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:61)
```

P.S.
На телефоне перед запуском всех приложений выдается "ошибка HTS Blink Feed". Во всех приложениях без `OnClickListener` вроде все норм, но стоит добавить метод `onClick()` и по нажатию на соответствующий элемент все летит к чертям. Помогите, люди.

Comment: Добавьте разметку лейаута и стектрейс ошибки после краша приложения.

Comment: Без логов ошибки помочь будет сложно. Также проясните - проблема только на этом конкретном девайсе или на всех остальных тоже? На эмуляторе пробовали? Но самое важное, конечно - логи ошибки

Comment: Стектрейс ? В смысле ошибки в консоли ?

Comment: Да. На вкладке Android Monitor.

Comment: Я новичок и  даже не знаю что такое логи.

Comment: Сейчас скину логи в комментарии.

Comment: У вас `id` для `TextView` в xml и коде не совпадают. Проблема в этом.

Comment: Логи сейчас будут в вопросе

Comment: Да славит род людской твой подвиг,  добрый человек под ником eudeneek. Все из-за id. Я идиот немножко.

Comment: Моя правка правда была такая плохая, да?

Comment: @Соколов, вернул как было :)

Comment: @diraria спасибо. Но 2 балла репутации rlyef отжал )